# Connect to PyBluez server using Android SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez, rfcomm, pybluez

I want to open RFCOMM socket connection between two devices, but nothing that I tried worked. This is what I have:

1. Python script uses PyBluez to advertise SPP service and waits for connections.
2. Android application tries to find that service and connect to the device.

---

**Server side**

Bluetooth server script advertises serial port profile service. The service UUID used is `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`.

```
bluetooth.advertise_service(
    sock=self.server_socket,
    name="My Service",
    service_id=self.service_uuid,
    service_classes=[self.service_uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
    profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE],
    description="My service description.",
)
```

**Client**

I can find the device to which I want to connect. To make a connection, I followed official Android documentation [Connect Bluetooth devices / Connect as a client](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices#connect-client) and used the same UUID as used on the server side. However, I get an exception `java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`.

Also, when scanning SDP server of the device that I want to connect to, I do find `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` service UUID, but it seems to be a default value, as it does not matter whether I advertise the service or not. Also, if I change the service UUID to something else, it does not show up. I tried clearing the cache both on both devices, but ti doesn't not change anything.

Moreover, I tried using `BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener` to get the information about the advertised services, but it does not find the serial port profile service that I advertise through the Python script that I mentioned earlier.

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, String serviceUuid) {
        BluetoothSocket tempSocket = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        try {
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(serviceUuid);
            tempSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(serviceUuid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("BluetoothClassicModule", "Socket's create() method failed", e);
        }

        mmSocket = tempSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            Log.d("BluetoothClassicModule", "[Thread] Began connecting to device " + mmDevice.getName());
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            Log.e("BluetoothClassicModule", "[THREAD] Could not connect to device.", connectException);

            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Log.e("BluetoothClassicModule", "[THREAD] Could not close the client socket.", closeException);
            }
            return;
        }

        Log.d("BluetoothClassicModule", "[THREAD] Connected successfully.");
    }
}
```

---

How could I make it work or at least debug this? I want to:

1. Find the device that advertises service with serial port profile and specific service UUID.
2. Establish RFCOMM connection to that device from Android application.